# User matching query does not exist. Viber bot Python

Tags: python, django, viber, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

Bot problem. When sending data, the bot gives an error related to the absence of a user match in the database. In this case, indeed, the user is not added to the base in the `proceed_request()` function.
What could be the problem? Thanks.

```
    def proceed_request(self, viber_request):
        if isinstance(viber_request, ViberMessageRequest):
            if not User.objects.filter(user_id=viber_request.sender.id).exists():
                User.objects.update_or_create(
                    user_id=viber_request.sender.id,
                    name=viber_request.sender.name,
                    country=viber_request.sender.country,
                    language=viber_request.sender.language
                )

    def send_confirmation(self, confirmation):
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user_id=User.objects.get(user_id=data.get('viber_id')).id,
            order_id=data.get('order_id'),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `if not User.objects.filter(...).exists()` is redundant as you already use `update_or_create`. In [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) you can find that there is `defaults` argument for what you want there:

```
def proceed_request(self, viber_request):
    if isinstance(viber_request, ViberMessageRequest):
        User.objects.update_or_create(
            user_id=viber_request.sender.id,
            defaults=dict(
                name=viber_request.sender.name,
                country=viber_request.sender.country,
                language=viber_request.sender.language
            )
        )

def send_confirmation(self, confirmation):
    order = Order.objects.create(
        user_id=User.objects.get(user_id=data.get('viber_id')).id,
        order_id=data.get('order_id'),
    )
```